# HTTP gzip compression does not save any time

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, http, gzip

I have a Spring Boot application that sometimes has to serve a very big JSON payload (several MB) over a REST API, which takes considerable time to download.

The data is read from a DB, serialized into JSON and sent back to the client.
The DB read operation is fast, even for big datasets, usually below 1 second. So my conclusion was that the most time consuming part is the HTTP exchange.

I've enabled GZIP compression for the HTTP exchange so the payload should be compressed before being sent. It seems this works (the returned payload is indeed compressed), however, there is no noticeable performance gain.

A `curl` request to the application's endpoint without compression takes 49 sec and yields a ~10 MB JSON payload:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>" --data-binary @priorities-request.json  'https://<REDACTED>/api/rest/priorities' > priorities-response.json                
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10.0M    0  9.9M  100 85081   205k   1715  0:00:49  0:00:49 --:--:--  239k
```

With GZIP compression enabled, the same request takes 42 sec and yields a ~260 kb GZip compressed JSON payload:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br" -H "Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>" --data-binary @priorities-request.json  'https://<REDACTED>/api/rest/priorities' > priorities-response.json 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  259k    0  176k  100 85081   4221   1991  0:00:42  0:00:42 --:--:-- 14408
```

My expectation would be that downloading a compressed 260K payload would take considerably less time than an uncompressed 10 MB download.

What's my mistake?

Edit: Because it's been asked in the comments how I set up the GZIP compression: I set `compression="on"` and `compressableMimeType="application/json"` in the `server.xml` of Tomcat. That's it. The rest is done by Tomcat's org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter class.

Edit 2: To rule out that serializing the data into JSON is where the time is lost, I tested locally with Jackson2JsonMessageConverter, but it took only about 0.5 seconds to write even a huge data structure into a 10MB JSON string.

Edit 3: What I find most puzzling is that the client application that consumes the API, which is running on another Tomcat instance on the same physical machine, still experiences the same delay when retrieving the data.

Comment: That you assume that compressing is free of cost, it isn't. Compressing the output also takes time. If you write to an in-memory `byte[]` like the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and zip that things might even take more time due to resizing, memory etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum gzip'ing 10MB of data takes about 0.06 seconds on my local machine, so that overhead hardly explains the observed behaviour.

Comment: gzip on the command line that doesn't mean it takes that amount of time in Java. However without seeing how you are doing GZIP or if you are leveraging the tomcat defaults it is impossible to help. I suspect the overhead is coming from both the GZIP and the fact that stuff is done in memory and that there is GC overhead and array creation involved.

Comment: @M.Deinum The Gzip compression is done completely outside our application code, it's all Spring Boot and Tomcat. We have no control over that. See my 1st edit to the question.

Comment: So you are using an external tomcat and not an embedded one. I have no idea what the performance of the `GzipOutputFiler` in Tomcat. What does your controller look like, how are you generating the JSON?

Comment: @M.Deinum the controller just returns a Map<String, List<PriorityGraph>> object, and the JSON serialization is done entirely by Spring Boot. It uses the ObjectMapper class from the Jackson2 framework. It's also out of our control.

Comment: As far as I understood the problem you are sending some payload to the server and take a snapshot on how long it took for the HTTP request to finish. What does the server actually do with the data? Have you 'CPU sampled' (profiled) the server to check what it did there? This way you should see where the server spent most CPU cycles at (= time spent). Maybe the processing of the actual uncompressed payload is the bottleneck and not the GZIP compression?! Without showing us code or how you configured things we can only guess

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment you might want to check what is taking up all that time. So not to measure only the whole HTTP requests but rather the different components. Could be that it is your query or mapping that takes most of the time. So measure the different moving parts instead of only focussing on the GZIP part.

Comment: @Roman Vottner I send a request to the application that contains a list of IDs, for which the application makes a query to the RDBMS and returns the result. The query has a lot of JOINs so the result can become quite large. We initially suspected the DB query to be the performance bottleneck, but it isn't. Profiling the application revealed that a request that took 42 seconds real time to complete only consumed 12 seconds of CPU time on the server (99% of which is the JSON serialization), so the rest seems to be I/O but I can't think of what it could be.

Comment: A difference of 30 seconds between consumed CPU time on the server and a response hitting your client sounds more like a time-out or the like. But again, this is only a guess because we have no insights into your setup and application logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out: It turned out the HTTP exchange didn't have anything to do with it.

The bottleneck was, in fact the database, but we didn't notice at first because the JPA query returns almost immediately.

What we weren't seeing was that lots of properties in the retrieved objects are loaded "lazily", so the DB queries for them are only executed when the JSON serializer accesses these properties. Those queries didn't use any CPU time on the Tomcat machine, so we couldn't detect the time loss by profiling.

Answer (score 0):

When you use gzip, there is a trade-off between CPU usage and bandwidth usage that needs to be considered. What comes as advantage for the end user (less transfer time i.e. faster download speed) will require additional CPU cycles at server side. 
The performance gain would certainly be visible if you run a load test. Also if your API is used internally by other APIs in your application, it will reduce the network usage drastically. The CPU usage may not be that significant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did a load test, JVisualVM says that processing the whole request takes 12 seconds in a worst case scenario. However the overall response time from the client's view is 110 seconds at worst, which means that there are still 58 seconds unexplained.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to send over the network a compressed data than may be compress it not when you read it from DB but when you write it to DB. That way the compression time will not be at all part of the request and you save on your storage space. Than disable HTTP compressin and read your compressed binary data from DB and send it over

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible. It's a relational database and the data must be saved in structured form to allow for SELECTs with conditions.

Comment: Than you can add the BLOB field to your table called compressed content and write into it your compressed content again at the stage of writing and when you need to read it for HTTP transmission just read and send that field.

Comment: Still not feasible. The data are the result of a complex SELECT. You can't do selects or joins on data that is inside a BLOB field.